# Can you see a solar eclipse from the International Space Station?

Tags: orbital-motion, solar-system, celestial-mechanics, satellites, eclipse

Inspired by last week's solar eclipse, I'm wondering under what conditions one can see a total solar eclipse from the ISS. How often does it happen? I guess it doesn't last very long because of the fast orbital speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's close enough to the earth to be well within the range of solar eclipses.   There's always going to be a solar eclipse somewhere in space because the moon will always cast a shadow behind it, well, except for when the moon is eclipsed by the earth.   But the moon's shadow passes over the earth just a small percentage of the time.

Given that the space station orbits the earth once every hour and a half, it's likely to see eclipses more often than you would see one on earth, assuming you didn't travel to see them.  The ratio should be the same, so if eclipses last 1/15th the time on the space station than they do on earth - which is probobly about right, then you should see them about 15 times as often.   Which, granted, still isn't very often.

Eclipses move across the earth, west to east, at about 1,000 MPH - well, depending on the latitude.   Closer to the poles, they move slower.    The moon orbits the earth at about 2,000 MPH, in the opposite direction that the earth rotates, so the net speed of the shadow is about 1,000 MPH.

http://sunearthday.nasa.gov/2006/faq.php

Here are some photos, though these appear to just be partial:  https://sociallyuncensored.com/entry/6896-solar-eclipse-from-space-aboard-the-international-space-station/

Here is the path of the 2017 eclipse, which is closer to the equator than the recent one, so it's path is longer.   There's a fair chance the shuttle will pass through that path, as it'll complete 2 orbits in that time.

http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEmono/TSE2017/TSE2017fig/TSE2017-1.gif